# Filter Array Element based on condition

Tags: php

I want to filter an array with some conditions.

I am generating a random sets of hotels for my travel portal where based on location all the permutations of Hotels should come.

The Conditions are :-
1. in 2 continues nights in same location should only get same hotel and roomtype.

My Approach ( i'm using array_filter()):

```
public static function my_function($item_values)
{
    for($i=0;$i<count($item_values);$i++){

        if($i>0){
            $j = $i-1;
            $preData = explode('-',$item_values[$j]);
            $data = explode('-',$item_values[$i]);
            if($data[0] == $preData[0]){
                if($data[1] == $preData[1]){
                    if($data[2] == $preData[2]){
                        return TRUE;
                    } else {
                        return FALSE;
                    }
                } else {
                    return FALSE;
                }
            } else {
                return FALSE;
            }
        } else {
        return true;
        }
    }
}
```

MY Array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-50-115
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-50-115
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-50-115
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-50-202
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-50-202
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-50-202
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-76-203
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-76-203
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-76-203
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-56-116
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-56-116
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-56-116
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-50-295
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-50-295
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-50-295
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-55-84
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-55-84
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-55-84
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-50-115
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-50-115
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-50-115
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-50-202
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-50-202
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-50-202
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-76-203
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-76-203
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-76-203
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-56-116
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [28] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-56-116
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-56-116
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-50-295
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [31] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-50-295
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [32] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-50-295
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [33] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-55-84
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [34] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-55-84
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [35] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-55-84
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [36] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-76-203
            [3] => 2-50-115
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [37] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-76-203
            [3] => 2-50-115
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [38] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-76-203
            [3] => 2-50-115
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [39] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-76-203
            [3] => 2-50-202
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [40] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-76-203
            [3] => 2-50-202
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [41] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-76-203
            [3] => 2-50-202
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [42] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-76-203
            [3] => 2-76-203
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [43] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-76-203
            [3] => 2-76-203
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [44] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-76-203
            [3] => 2-76-203
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [45] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-76-203
            [3] => 2-56-116
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [46] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-76-203
            [3] => 2-56-116
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [47] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-76-203
            [3] => 2-56-116
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [48] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-76-203
            [3] => 2-50-295
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [49] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-76-203
            [3] => 2-50-295
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [50] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-76-203
            [3] => 2-50-295
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [51] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-76-203
            [3] => 2-55-84
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [52] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-76-203
            [3] => 2-55-84
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [53] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-76-203
            [3] => 2-55-84
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [54] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-56-116
            [3] => 2-50-115
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [55] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-56-116
            [3] => 2-50-115
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [56] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-56-116
            [3] => 2-50-115
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [57] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-56-116
            [3] => 2-50-202
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [58] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-56-116
            [3] => 2-50-202
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [59] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-56-116
            [3] => 2-50-202
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [60] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-56-116
            [3] => 2-76-203
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [61] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-56-116
            [3] => 2-76-203
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [62] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-56-116
            [3] => 2-76-203
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [63] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-56-116
            [3] => 2-56-116
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [64] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-56-116
            [3] => 2-56-116
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [65] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-56-116
            [3] => 2-56-116
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [66] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-56-116
            [3] => 2-50-295
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [67] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-56-116
            [3] => 2-50-295
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [68] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-56-116
            [3] => 2-50-295
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [69] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-56-116
            [3] => 2-55-84
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [70] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-56-116
            [3] => 2-55-84
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [71] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-56-116
            [3] => 2-55-84
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [72] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-295
            [3] => 2-50-115
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [73] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-295
            [3] => 2-50-115
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [74] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-295
            [3] => 2-50-115
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [75] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-295
            [3] => 2-50-202
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [76] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-295
            [3] => 2-50-202
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [77] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-295
            [3] => 2-50-202
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [78] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-295
            [3] => 2-76-203
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [79] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-295
            [3] => 2-76-203
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [80] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-295
            [3] => 2-76-203
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [81] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-295
            [3] => 2-56-116
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [82] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-295
            [3] => 2-56-116
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [83] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-295
            [3] => 2-56-116
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [84] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-295
            [3] => 2-50-295
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [85] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-295
            [3] => 2-50-295
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [86] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-295
            [3] => 2-50-295
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [87] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-295
            [3] => 2-55-84
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [88] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-295
            [3] => 2-55-84
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [89] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-50-295
            [3] => 2-55-84
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [90] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-55-84
            [3] => 2-50-115
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [91] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-55-84
            [3] => 2-50-115
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [92] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-55-84
            [3] => 2-50-115
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [93] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-55-84
            [3] => 2-50-202
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [94] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-55-84
            [3] => 2-50-202
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [95] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-55-84
            [3] => 2-50-202
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [96] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-55-84
            [3] => 2-76-203
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [97] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-55-84
            [3] => 2-76-203
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [98] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-55-84
            [3] => 2-76-203
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [99] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-55-84
            [3] => 2-56-116
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [100] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-55-84
            [3] => 2-56-116
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [101] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-55-84
            [3] => 2-56-116
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [102] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-55-84
            [3] => 2-50-295
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [103] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-55-84
            [3] => 2-50-295
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [104] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-55-84
            [3] => 2-50-295
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [105] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-55-84
            [3] => 2-55-84
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [106] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-55-84
            [3] => 2-55-84
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [107] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-4-13
            [2] => 2-55-84
            [3] => 2-55-84
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [108] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-50-115
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [109] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-50-115
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [110] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-50-115
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [111] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-50-202
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [112] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-50-202
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [113] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-50-202
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [114] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-76-203
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [115] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-76-203
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [116] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-76-203
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [117] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-56-116
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [118] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-56-116
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [119] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-56-116
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [120] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-50-295
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [121] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-50-295
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [122] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-50-295
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [123] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-55-84
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [124] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-55-84
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [125] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-115
            [3] => 2-55-84
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [126] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-50-115
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [127] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-50-115
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [128] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-50-115
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [129] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-50-202
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [130] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-50-202
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [131] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-50-202
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [132] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-76-203
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [133] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-76-203
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [134] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-76-203
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [135] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-56-116
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [136] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-56-116
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [137] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-56-116
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [138] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-50-295
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [139] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-50-295
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [140] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-50-295
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [141] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-55-84
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [142] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-55-84
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    [143] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-50-202
            [3] => 2-55-84
            [4] => 1-100-269
        )

    [144] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-76-203
            [3] => 2-50-115
            [4] => 1-4-13
        )

    [145] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1-100-271
            [2] => 2-76-203
            [3] => 2-50-115
            [4] => 1-100-271
        )

    ...

)
```

So, in array element [1] => 1-100-269 Depicts as:

[1] == Key & Night.
1 is the Location Id.
100 is the hotel id
269 is the roomtype id.

i am expecting array is only same hotel and roomtype in same locations for different night. But i am getting all the 323 array elements.

Any Help is appreciated.

My Expected Array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[1] => 1-4-13
[2] => 2-50-115
[3] => 2-50-115
[4] => 1-4-13
)

[1] => Array
(
[1] => 1-4-13
[2] => 2-50-115
[3] => 2-50-115
[4] => 1-100-271
)

[2] => Array
(
[1] => 1-4-13
[2] => 2-50-115
[3] => 2-50-115
[4] => 1-100-269
)

[3] => Array
(
[1] => 1-4-13
[2] => 2-50-202
[3] => 2-50-202
[4] => 1-4-13
)

[4] => Array
(
[1] => 1-4-13
[2] => 2-50-202
[3] => 2-50-202
[4] => 1-100-271
)

[5] => Array
(
[1] => 1-4-13
[2] => 2-50-202
[3] => 2-50-202
[4] => 1-100-269
)


[6] => Array
(
[1] => 1-4-13
[2] => 2-76-203
[3] => 2-76-203
[4] => 1-4-13
)

[7] => Array
(
[1] => 1-4-13
[2] => 2-76-203
[3] => 2-76-203
[4] => 1-100-271
)

[8] => Array
(
[1] => 1-4-13
[2] => 2-76-203
[3] => 2-76-203
[4] => 1-100-269
)

[9] => Array
(
[1] => 1-4-13
[2] => 2-56-116
[3] => 2-56-116
[4] => 1-4-13
)

[10] => Array
(
[1] => 1-4-13
[2] => 2-56-116
[3] => 2-56-116
[4] => 1-100-271
)

[11] => Array
(
[1] => 1-4-13
[2] => 2-56-116
[3] => 2-56-116
[4] => 1-100-269
)

[12] => Array
(
[1] => 1-4-13
[2] => 2-50-295
[3] => 2-50-295
[4] => 1-4-13
)

[13] => Array
(
[1] => 1-4-13
[2] => 2-50-295
[3] => 2-50-295
[4] => 1-100-271
)

[14] => Array
(
[1] => 1-4-13
[2] => 2-50-295
[3] => 2-50-295
[4] => 1-100-269
)

[15] => Array
(
[1] => 1-4-13
[2] => 2-55-84
[3] => 2-55-84
[4] => 1-4-13
)

[16] => Array
(
[1] => 1-4-13
[2] => 2-55-84
[3] => 2-55-84
[4] => 1-100-271
)

[17] => Array
(
[1] => 1-4-13
[2] => 2-55-84
[3] => 2-55-84
[4] => 1-100-269
)

[18] => Array
(
[1] => 1-100-271
[2] => 2-50-115
[3] => 2-50-115
[4] => 1-4-13
)

[19] => Array
(
[1] => 1-100-271
[2] => 2-50-115
[3] => 2-50-115
[4] => 1-100-271
)

[20] => Array
(
[1] => 1-100-271
[2] => 2-50-115
[3] => 2-50-115
[4] => 1-100-269
)

[21] => Array
(
[1] => 1-100-271
[2] => 2-50-202
[3] => 2-50-202
[4] => 1-4-13
)

[22] => Array
(
[1] => 1-100-271
[2] => 2-50-202
[3] => 2-50-202
[4] => 1-100-271
)

[23] => Array
(
[1] => 1-100-271
[2] => 2-50-202
[3] => 2-50-202
[4] => 1-100-269
)
)
```

Comment: what is your expected output? and can you share your array in JSON format so we can try at our end

Comment: kindly check my edit. i have updated my expected array.